# Chrome App app - server space for storing leaderboard

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have created and published a app (a game basically) on chrome web store.
Now i want to maintain a leaderboard for the best scores obtained in each level of the game.

Where can I get a free server space to store/retrieve the leaderboard?

Does chrome store has any inherent support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome extensions/apps have sync storage options that are provided for free with a Google account. But not a centralized service to collect data (if you do not take Google Analytics into account).

Sticking with Google ecosystem, though, you might look into 
[Google Apps Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine).

There's a certain free quota and your usage might fit into that. Then again, it might not, but worth a look.

---

Here's a few links on the topic:

SO: [How to implement internet high scores in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609735/how-to-implement-internet-high-scores-in-google-app-engine)

Google blogs: [Building scalable social games on App Engine](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2012/10/building-scalable-social-games-on-app_18.html)

Google blogs: [Google Code Jam's Ranking Library](http://googleappengine.blogspot.ch/2009/01/google-code-jams-ranking-library.html)

Github: [Pre-made GAE server "omgleaderboards"](https://github.com/omgwtfgames/omgleaderboards)

Comment: in fact I am using the chrome storage sync for storing individual scores. let me check this apps engine.

Comment: @prembhaskal Updated my answer with some links

Comment: Thanks. we deployed one java servlet (for maintaining leaderboard) in the app engine.. and our chrome_app requests for this data using ajax. works like charm :)